# Jinja2 template does not print query results. "UndefinedError: 'q' is undefined"

Tags: python-2.7, html-table, jinja2

```
class TablePage(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        ID_id = self.request.get('ID')
        key = db.Key.from_path("PQ", ID_id)
        p = PQ.get(key)
        qs = db.Query(QA)
        qs.ancestor(p)
        result = qs.get()

        template_values = {'qs': qs,
                        'p': p
            }
        self.render_template('table.html',  template_values )
```

I am asking this question because I am trying to put the queried records into an html table. Are my template_values correct and adequate or do I have to include the values of the variable "result" in template_values somehow also?

Using the same kind of "for" loop in my python code as I used in the jinja2 template, I have added this extra debugging code which shows that there are two instances of QA in qs, but the error persists.

```
for q in qs:
            answers = q.answers
            logging.info("answers %s" % answers )



INFO     2012-07-05 09:23:03,853 views.py:84] answers [0L, 0L, 0L]
INFO     2012-07-05 09:23:03,853 views.py:84] answers [0L, 0L, 0L]
```

I am trying this but the jinja2 template does not seem to be getting the information correctly. For example I have the following template code which produces the error "UndefinedError: 'q' is undefined"

```
<tbody>
{% for q in qs %}
    <tr>
    <td> {{ q.seqnum }} </td>
    <td> {{ q.question }} </td>
        {% for answer in q.answers %}
        <td> {{ answer }} </td>
        {% endfor %}
    <td> {{ q.answers|sum() }} </td>
{% endfor %}
<td>{{ q.date }}</td>
<td>{{ q.modified }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

The {% endfor %} in the html template was premature; it needs to be after all the q.xxx values. d'oh

Sorry for wasting other's time.